# How to have checkbox in each row enter values in respective row

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Sample Excel Screenshot]

I have a checkbox in each row of column K {Checkbox1, Checkbox2, etc.}  I want each checkbox to put an "X" in each respective row.  I have this code to do it for one of the checkboxes:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Range(Cells(3, 12), Cells(3, 35)).Value = "X"
    Else
        Range(Cells(3, 12), Cells(3, 35)).Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

But I want this for all the checkboxes and plan to have around 30 checkboxes.  Is it possible to assign a variable i to have checkboxi and each row depend on the variable?

Comment: You can use `.TopLeftCell` to find the row but the simplest would be to use a Datavalidation in Col K and then use the `Worksheet_Change` Event. I have answered this kind of  questiion before but finding it is a problem. Let me see if I manage to find it...

Comment: You can achieve this using data validation combined with an IF statement of `=if(K2="True","X","")` This would circumvent the need for code and probably speed up your spreadsheet so it isn't updating every time anything changes. If you find this sufficient I'll put it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Siddarth Rout, this is what I’m looking for. I will try to look for more information on Worksheet_Change. Please let me know if you happen to find your past posts.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion Mark S. I didn’t want to use this method because I want to limit the values in columns L and forward using Data_Validation. I’m creating this for users to input information that gets used downstream, so I don’t want them to put something other than an X. I couldn’t find a way to have a formula and Data_Validation at the same time. Do you know if it’s possible to simultaneously have the if formula and limit values to X?

Comment: Thanks!  When I use your code, for the second sub, it is says Checkbox variable not defined.  If I define Dim Checkbox As Checkbox, there is a runtime error 13 type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a multipart procedure.

**Create a new Module**

In the VBAProject Window
        Right Click on the Microsoft Excel Objects 
        Select Insert
        Select Module

Copy/Paste the below macros in the new Module

```
Sub AsgnOnAction()
Dim ckBx As CheckBox, Rng As Range

    For Each ckBx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        ckBx.OnAction = "CkBxClk"
    Next ckBx
End Sub


Sub CkBxClk()
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("K3:K" & Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each CheckBox In Rng
        If CheckBox.Value = True Then CheckBox.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 24).Value = "X"
        If CheckBox.Value = False Then CheckBox.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 24).Value = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

**Run AsgnOnAction()** to update all the checkboxes **.OnAction** parameter

Goto your worksheet and **Right Click** one of the checkboxes to verify that the macro has been assigned.

**Select a checkbox** and an X will be pasted to your range. When you deselect a checkbox all Xs will be removed.

I hope this helps